# Arp Reply With Wrong IP - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: arp

This system is Ubuntu 20.04.  It has a disabled wireless interface.  It uses an onboard Ethernet port.   I have a machine that is IP'd 10.0.0.142.  It replies to pings on the local network at 10.0.0.142 and 10.0.0.20.

Here is output from ifconfig and tcpdump.  You can see the arp reply from this box is saying its 10.0.0.20. ifconfig shows its only configured to be 10.0.0.142.

This causes all sorts of issues with networking.

Anyone know why this would happen?

```
$ ifconfig | more
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.142  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        ether 60:44:55:66:6e:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24993370  bytes 18152361859 (18.1 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5264383  bytes 582006728 (582.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 37817  bytes 3451024 (3.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 37817  bytes 3451024 (3.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp3s0 host 10.0.0.20
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
02:53:32.412454 IP 10.0.0.60 > 10.0.0.20: ICMP echo request, id 25, seq 58039, length 40
02:53:32.412499 IP 10.0.0.20 > 10.0.0.60: ICMP echo reply, id 25, seq 58039, length 40
02:53:38.397740 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.20 (60:44:55:66:6e:c2 (oui Unknown)) tell 10.0.0.60, length 46
02:53:38.397767 ARP, Reply 10.0.0.20 is-at 60:44:55:66:6e:c2 (oui Unknown), length 28
02:53:38.412193 IP 10.0.0.60 > 10.0.0.20: ICMP echo request, id 25, seq 58041, length 40
```

Comment: Could it be that another device with the same MAC address is on the network? I don't know if it's possible, but could there be another interface in a different network namespace but connected to this network? Another observation: It's strange that the OUI is unknown for something that looks like a physical NIC. I just [confirmed](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html) this myself.

Comment: Without digging (or thinking!) too deeply yet... What is in your ARP cache at the time this happens? (`sudo arp`)

Comment: @A.B The thing is, `10.0.0.20 is-at 60:44:55:66:6e:c2`. This is the same MAC address as enp3s0. But you are right, of course; `ifconfig` is an outdated tool by now.

Comment: @C.M. 
I thought this too, but nothing in the arp cache.   I'm so confused as to why this interface would answer on 10.0.0.20 when its not assigned.  
arp is ->
arp -vn
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.0.0.1                 ether   d4:aa:bb:cc:46:51   C                     enp3s0
10.0.0.2                 ether   30:cd:aa:bb:cc:c4   C                     enp3s0
10.0.0.60                ether   e8:aa:bb:cc:b5:94   C                     enp3s0

arp -v -d 10.0.0.20
arp: SIOCDARP(dontpub)
arp: SIOCDARP(pub)
No ARP entry for 10.0.0.20

Comment: Can you now also edit the question and replace the output of `ifconfig` with  the output of `ip address`?

Comment: @Durinsom: When providing requested detail, please **edit** your original question so it appears in the question, not the comments. It's easier to format/read in the question text than in comments, and if others come across the question they can see the info without having to dig through the comments. I would also like to see the output of `ip address` to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Also, I was not clear.. Be sure to fully populate the arp cache before printing it. Do a network broadcast ping just prior: `sudo ping -n -c 1 -b 10.0.0.255` . (Or all a once: `sudo ping -n -c 1 -b 10.0.0.255 && arp` .)

Comment: @berndaush: Just FYI--no sure about Ubunu, but my Deb10 install defaulted to randomizing the MAC in something very similar, I have a WiFi extender that modifies the MACs of machines is relaying/extending, _and_ one of my paranoid family members uses a MAC randomizer in fear of.. whatever. So I am used to seeing unknown OUIs.